# How to use try/catch when save two entitys as one transaction?

Tags: try-catch

I have two entitys: User and UserRole. It is realized as tables in DB and classes with the same names. If I create new user I must create userrole for him. If there is exception during user creation or userrole creation user musn't be created. Question is that I don't know how to set try catch blockes. I have some alternatives:

1)

```
try
{
  UserDA.BeginTransaction();
  try
  {
    UserDA.Save(newUser);
    UserDA.CommitTransaction();
  }
  catch()
  {
   throw SomeException;
   UserDA.RollbackTransaction();
  }

  UserRoleDA.BeginTransaction();
  try
  {
    UserRoleDA.Save(newUser);
    UserRoleDA.CommitTransaction();
  }
  catch()
  {
   throw SomeException;
   UserRoleDA.RollbackTransaction();
  }
}
catch()
{
  //catch user creation exception
}
```

2)

```
UserDA.BeginTransaction();
try
{
  UserDA.Save(newUser);
  UserDA.CommitTransaction();
  UserRoleDA.BeginTransaction();
      try
      {
        UserRoleDA.Save(newUser);
        UserRoleDA.CommitTransaction();
      }
      catch()
      {
       throw SomeException;
       UserRoleDA.RollbackTransaction();
      }
}
catch()
{
  //catch 
  UserDA.RollbackTransaction();
}
```

May be someone know more correct way.

Comment: Do you have to commit the transaction creating the user before creating the role?  Not only aren't you specifying the language, you aren't specifying the database.

Comment: Why are you breaking up the transactions to have only one statement each?  The whole point of a transaction is to run multiple statements within one atomic scope.  Each individual statement wouldn't need a transaction on its own because it's already atomic.

Answer (score 2):

The general way of doing this is:

```
Try{
    StartTransaction
    ...do work...
    CommitTransaction
}
catch(Exception)
{
    RollbackTransaction
}
```

That way anything thrown while doing work causes the whole transaction to rollback. Only if you reach the end of ...do work... without an exception being thrown does commit get called.